# Best practices for Android databases

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My Android application needs a local database. Which is the best manner for this? which class sub I use, subclass, reimplement, etc. I have found too much information on the net but I still don't know which are the best practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pretty broad question and depends a little on your level on experience and usage.

But the common practice is to create your own [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) which will abstract the access to the database. This way you can use `Uri` to execute select/update/delete/insert queries.

For the SQLite database itself, use [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to abstract the creation and upgrading of your SQLite database. This will allow you to upgrade your database without the user losing all of his data in an easy manner.

I can attach a piece of code I used in one of my older projects which get you started. But implementing the whole thing may be out of scope of a single question/answer.

```
public class MyServiceProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // Initialize the database and assign it to the private variable
        MyDatabaseHelper sqlHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        return (db == null)?false:true;
    }

    @override
    Cursor query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // handle the query here, form it, do your checks and then access the DB
        db.query(....);
    }
}

class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyAppTag";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "Databasename";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tablename";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static MyServiceProvider.CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.mycompany.myApp.MyAppService/myTableOrIdentifier");

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Here you can perform updates when the database structure changes
        // Begin transaction
        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            if(oldVersion<2){
                // Upgrade database structure from Version 1 to 2
                String alterTable = "ALTER ....";

                db.execSQL(alterTable);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Successfully upgraded to Version 2");
            }
            // This allows you to upgrade from any version to the next most 
            // recent one in multiple steps as you don't know if the user has
            // skipped any of the previous updates
            if(oldVersion<3){
                // Upgrade database structure from Version 2 to 3
                String alterTable = "ALTER ....";

                db.execSQL(alterTable);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Successfully upgraded to Version 3");
            }

            // Only when this code is executed, the changes will be applied 
            // to the database
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Ends transaction
            // If there was an error, the database won't be altered
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use cursors to interact with the database.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
...
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(
        // The Uri results in content://com.mycompany.myApp.MyAppService/myTableOrIdentifier/someId
        Uri.withAppendedPath(MyServiceProvider.CONTENT_URI, someId),
        new String[] {
            // only get fields we need!
            "MyDbFieldIneed"
        },
        null, null, null);
```

This will return a [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) which will you can iterate through and get the results. This is also how most things in Android are implemented (i.e. obtaining an Address from the address book works via Uri and Cursor too).

**Edit:** 
I realized the links are hard to see with the code highlights. Here the link of important classes you will need.

- [ContentProvider | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)
- [SQLiteOpenHelper | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)
- [Cursor | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
- [UriMatcher | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html)

**Edit 2:**
Also if you work with multiple tables, [`UriMatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html) is an important source too

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me an example of how do you declare the contentResolver object?

Comment: It's easy. `getContentResolver()` is a method of `Context` which `Activity` derive from (actually `Activity` derives from `ContextThemeWrapper` which derives from `ContextWrapper` which derives from `Context`). So a simple `ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();` Will do it

Answer (score 4):

I guess the best way to use SQLite databases is to use ContentProviders. When you search for it you will see that ContentProvider API is very complicated. But there is a very good library that makes the process actually very easy. It is called ProviGen and you can find a detailed information about it in the link below.

https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/ProviGen

It is very easy to use. You will just create a Contract class where you will indicate what columns you need in the database using annotation and it will create everything automatically. I can even create multiple tables in one database.

Comment: +1 for `ContentProvider`s. But I disagree that they are complicated. Once you got it once it is pretty simple. It just requires a little bit more code to start with, but that's valid for most patterns. MVVM/MVC pattern require quite some code to get started in the first place too, but are valid patterns and easy to maintain later on.

Comment: When you have 2 or 3 tables in your SQLite database which is tied to the ContentProvider the things become complicated even more. ProviGen does it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the best practice is to use a framework, that will do most of the work for you. I personally prefer ORM mapping when working with databases, so I would recommend to try some ORM framework. The best one I know is [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml). The author also answers questions here on SO, which can be quite useful.

But if you do not want to use it, you should start by reading these articles:

- [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
- [Using databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite would be the answer.

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

**`Which is the best manner for this?`**
You need to use `SQLite` which comes with Android. Every Android app can have its own database.

**`which class sub I use, subclass, reimplement,`**
You need to extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` class which determines what the name of your database is, how is it upgraded / downgraded, how the tables are structured and so on. It also defines methods to get a reference to the database.

Yes, a lot of resources are out there and not are brain-friendly and quality resources. Here are some that I like:
[SQLite and COntentProvider by Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
[Prof. Gustin's Android Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA13A9BE90783105A)

As for the title of your question **`Best practices for Android databases`** all I can say is that all the best practices that apply for SQL databases apply here like normalization, etc